# cancel filter and sorting of big data array

Tags: swift, sorting, filter, realm, cancellation

I'm building vocabulary app using realm. I have several objects of Vocabulary, which contains list of words. One vocabulary contains 45000 words

UI is build such way, that user can search by "BEGINSWITH", "CONTAINS" or "ENDSWITH" through word's title, if corresponding tab is selected.

As, there are several vocabularies, there are some words, that appear in several vocabularies, and I need to remove "duplicates" from UI.

When I do this filtering duplicates on resulted objects + sorting them alphabetically the UI of app freezes, till process completes.

My question is:
1) How can I cancel previous filter and realm filtering request, if tab changed (for example from Contains to Ends"?
2) How can I do all these filter/sorting requests in background, so UI will not freeze?

My code:

```
    let vocabularyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "enabled == 1 AND lang_from CONTAINS[c] %@", self.language.value)

    self.vocabularies = Array(realm.objects(Vocabulary.self).filter(vocabularyPredicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "display_order"))

    let result = List<Word>()

    for object in self.vocabularies {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title \(selectedFilter.value)[c] %@", self.query.value.lowercased())
        result.append(objectsIn: object.words.filter(predicate))
    }

    self.words = Array(result).unique{$0.title}.sorted {
        (s1, s2) -> Bool in return s1.title.localizedStandardCompare(s2.title) == .orderedAscending
    }
```

selectedFilter.value is selected tab value: "BEGINSWITH", "CONTAINS" or "ENDSWITH"
self.query.value.lowercased() - search query.

unique{$0.title} is extension method for array

```
extension Array {
    func unique<T:Hashable>(map: ((Element) -> (T)))  -> [Element] {
        var set = Set<T>() //the unique list kept in a Set for fast retrieval
        var arrayOrdered = [Element]() //keeping the unique list of elements but ordered
        for value in self {
            if !set.contains(map(value)) {
                set.insert(map(value))
                arrayOrdered.append(value)
            }
        }

        return arrayOrdered
    }
}
```

Actually, realm search is pretty fast, but because of looping through vocabularies and filtering duplicates + sorting alphabetically operations through array of objects - request is freezing for 1-2 seconds.

**UPDATE, based on [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce) and [Manuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9333431/manuel) advices:**

I have lurked one more time, and it appeared, that .distinct(by: [keypath]) is already presented in Results in new version of RealmSwift.

I have changed filter/sorting request to

```
realm.objects(Word.self).filter(vocabularyPredicate).distinct(by: ["title"]).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)
```

works better know, but I want to ensure, UI will not freeze anyway, by passing objects bettween background thread and UI thread. I have updated adviced construction to:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let cachedWords = CashedWords()

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "enabled == 1")
        let results = realm.objects(Word.self).filter(predicate).distinct(by: ["title"]).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)

        cachedWords.words.append(objectsIn: results)

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(cachedWords)
        }

        let wordsRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: cachedWords)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let realm = try! Realm()

            guard let wordsResult = realm.resolve(wordsRef) else {
                return
            }

            self.words = Array(wordsResult.words)

            if ((self.view.window) != nil) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        print("data reload finalized")
    }
```

Comment: If you want to remove "duplicates", then why not just use `distinct()`?

Comment: How can I use it? Can you show an example please? As I lurked, there is no distinct function in realm yet.

Comment: I have lurked, and it appeared, that .distinct(by: [keypath]) is already presented in Results<T>. I have changed filter/sorting request to 

realm.objects(Word.self).filter(vocabularyPredicate).distinct(by: ["title"]).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)

works better know, but I want to ensure, UI will not freeze anyway. So, I will update the issue.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what I was reading (thanks, git) but yeah, you are right, `Results.distinct(by)` was added in 3.1.0 (2018-01-16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1) How can I cancel previous filter and realm filtering request, if tab changed (for example from Contains to Ends"?*

You could create an NSOperation to perform the task and check if it's been cancelled between each of the steps (fetch, check isCancelled, filter, check isCancelled, sort). You won't get to cancel it immediately, but it could improve your performance. It also depends on which of those three steps (fetch, filter, sort) is taking longer...

*2) How can I do all these filter/sorting requests in background, so UI will not freeze?*

You could run that operation inside a new NSOperationQueue.
Or just use GCD, dispatch a block to a background queue, create a Realm instance in the block and run your code there, then dispatch the results back to the main queue to update the UI.
Something like this:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

    guard let realm = try? Realm() else {
        return // maybe pass an empty array back to the main queue?
    }

    // ...
    // your code here
    // ...

    let words = Array(result).unique{$0.title}.sorted {
        (s1, s2) -> Bool in return s1.title.localizedStandardCompare(s2.title) == .orderedAscending
    }
    // Can't pass Realm objects directly across threads
    let wordReferences = words.map { ThreadSafeReference(to: $0) }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Resolve references on main thread
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let mainThreadWords = wordReferences.flatMap { realm.resolve($0) }
        // Do something with words
        self.words = mainThreadWords
    }
}
```

Additionally, you should try to optimize your query:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "vocabulary.enabled == 1 AND vocabulary.lang_from CONTAINS[c] %@ AND title \(selectedFilter.value)[c] %@", self.language.value, self.query.value.lowercased())
let words = realm.objects(Word.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
let wordsReference = ThreadSafeReference(words)
// resolve this wordsReference in the main thread
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did everything as you wrote, but receive crash now:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'

Comment: Ah sorry, you can't pass Realm objects across threads just like that. I have updated my answer to use ThreadSafeReference. Depending on how long it takes to resolve the references on the main thread it might be better to update your query to produce a single 'Results<Word>' type and create a single ThreadSafeReference to that.

Comment: huh, it works now, thank you! But it takes 10 seconds to filter and sorts results + 13 seconds to pass object to main thread. I think there should be any faster soltuon

Comment: Well as I said, you might be able to optimize your query to make it take less time and also pass the results back so there's only one reference to resolve. I updated the answer with a suggestion to use a single query to fetch the words, hopefully that would improve the speed?

Comment: thank you very much for continious help. Unfortunately, because of app architecture, Vocabulary contains list of words, and Word do not has Vocabulary. That's why 'Property 'vocabulary' not found in object of type 'Word''

Actually, we are changing model now, and copy lang_from and enabled to Word object. Hopefully, I will be able to filter/sort without Sorting of swift Array.

Will check and write about final results